# Vue.js 2.x: `v-model` and `:type`

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

`:type` is not supported by `v-model`, but works with `:value` + `@input`.

If it is just syntactic sugar, why the difference?

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events

Could there be issues with `<input :type="type" :value="value" @input="value = $event.target.value">` ?